# UUID_SHORT regenerate if duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (users_uuid, type_id) VALUES (UUID_SHORT(), :type_id)";
```

My question is if in case the `UUID_SHORT()` generated already exists, is there any way to tell MySQL to generate another `UUID_SHORT()` within that query? What I have in my mind now is to trap the return error response then execute again the query, which I find inefficient.

Based @eicto comment, I read `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` then tried to reconstruct my query, I achieve a new query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (users_uuid, type_id) VALUES (UUID_SHORT(), :type_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (users_uuid) = VALUES(UUID_SHORT())";
```

However I received an error in my log that states:

**"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(users_uuid) = VALUES(UUID_SHORT())' at line 1"**

What does this mean?

Comment: Create unique constraint for `users_uuid` column. PS: why don't you use autoincrement instead?

Comment: What do you mean? The column `users_uuid` already has unique attribute. The primary key for that table is column `users_id` is already `AUTO_INCREMENTED`, I just need those value of `UUID_SHORT()` for some other use that I don't want to use my autoincremented column value.

Comment: as long as it already covered by an unique constraint - just check if the query successful, and if it's not - repeat the query.

Comment: [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I updated my query is this correct? `$query = "INSERT INTO users (users_uuid, type_id) VALUES (UUID_SHORT(), :type_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users_uuid=UUID()";`

Comment: i think the syntax is users_uuid=values(etc